# File Attribute of X

Tags: windows, file-attributes

I have a file on my Windows 7 machine with the attributes of HX. I understand H means hidden, but what does X mean?

Comment: Do you have BitLocker enabled on the machine?

Comment: Pretty sure it means extended based upon a random conversation I had years ago. But I only found 1 reference https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Windows 7 machine handy, but try asking for help on `attrib`:

```
attrib /?
```

On Windows XP, all the attribute letters are listed in the help.

Comment: This also works on Windows 7 but it doesn't show an x

Comment: attrib only shows the four base attributes: RASH

Comment: The `attrib` that you use may not; [better `attrib`s](http://jpsoft.com./help/attrib.htm) show a lot more, however.

Comment: No, the "X" attribute displayed in Windows Explorer is **not the same** as the "X" displayed in "attrib" command. Explorer's "X" attribute is the reserved "Device" attribute (bit 6, if using zero-based indexing); "attrib" command's "X" is No Scrub (bit 17) which is a new attribute introduced in Windows 8 / Server 2012.

Answer (score 0):

There are no such attribute specification about X in attrib. check about attrib on [wikipidea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attrib) ..

I got something informative about this from stackover flow question. follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808598/how-to-create-an-undeletable-file-in-delphi)

the file had the HX attributes set in place); however, the attribute approach lead me nowhere, as I can't find any documented feature on the existence of a file attribute X.

Answer (score 0):

I can't add comment, and this is not so much of an answer.
Please visit my question regarding [file attribute X on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617639/how-to-set-clear-attribute-x-on-files-with-in-c).

Short answer: the file has attribute 
`FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DEVICE
64 (0x40)` ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg258117%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Comment: Can you expand your answer to include the relevant parts of the link?