# How to make a file non-deletable on an USB drive?

Tags: windows, filesystems, fat32, file-attributes

Somebody used my USB drive and upon returning it to me, I found a `autorun.inf` that is undeleteable.
I tried changing it's file attribute which is only H (not even set as a system file) but it keeps on saying Access Denied.

The USB is set on FAT32, upon asking my friend, he told me that he uses [Panda USB Vaccine](http://research.pandasecurity.com/Panda-USB-and-AutoRun-Vaccine/)

How do they do this?
Im trying to use some Disk Sector editor but have no idea which hex file they change to make this kind of file and make it deletable again.
Formatting the drive removes it, but I'm curious as to how to be able to set those kind of file attribute.

Comment: I found another tool that does the same [link](http://labs.bitdefender.com/projects/usb-immunizer/overview)  BitDefender USB Immunizer

Comment: Did you inspect the permissions on the file?

Comment: @Moab The filesystem on the USB is FAT32.

Comment: In Windows 7 or later, the autorun.inf created by Panda USB Vaccine will be  displayed with file attributes "HX", while "H" means hidden and "X" means the reserved FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DEVICE.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Test method

Panda doesn't seem to reveal the exact mechanism of its "vaccine", which is understandable, since it's basically [security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity). If you know how it works, you can reverse the effects and the "vaccine" becomes useless.

I downloaded and installed [Panda USB Vaccine](http://research.pandasecurity.com/Panda-USB-and-AutoRun-Vaccine/) and "vaccinated" my flash drive, dumped the flash drive's partition with [dd for windows](http://www.chrysocome.net/dd) using the commands

```
dd --list

dd if=\\.\Volume{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx} of=C:\vaccinated.img
```

where `xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx` is the GUID provided by the first command, opened `c:\vaccinated.img` in a hex editor and searched for `AUTORUN`.

### What USB Vaccine does

The entry for `AUTORUN.INF` begins with the following twelve bytes:

```
41 55 54 4F 52 55 4E 20 49 4E 46 42
```

The first eleven bytes are just the space-padded [8.3 filename](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename): `AUTORUN INF`

The last byte specifies the file's attributes, and its binary representation is:

```
01000010
```

According to the [Microsoft EFI FAT32 File System Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463080.aspx), this last byte is a bit field that takes the following form:

```
XYADVSHR
```

where the bits `A`, `D`, `V`, `S`, `H` and `R` are `1` if and only if the file is archived, a directory, the volume ID<sup>1</sup>, a system file, hidden or read-only. `AUTORUN.INF` is hidden, since `H` is set to `1`.

The bits `X` and `Y` are reserved and should both be `0`. However, USB Vaccine sets `Y` to `1`.

### What the specification says

> The upper two bits of the attribute byte are reserved and should always be set to 0 when a file is created and never modified or looked at after that.

Furthermore, it recommends for validation of directory contents:

> These guidelines are provided so that disk maintenance utilities can verify individual directory entries for 'correctness' while maintaining compatibility with future enhancements to the directory structure.
>
> 1. *DO NOT* look at the content of directory entry fields marked *reserved* and assume that, if they are any value other than zero, that they are "bad".
> 2. *DO NOT* reset the content of directory entry fields marked *reserved* to zero when they contain non-zero values (under the assumption that they are "bad").  Directory entry fields are designated *reserved*, rather than *must-be-zero*. They should be ignored by your application. These fields are intended for future extensions of the file system. By ignoring them an utility can continue to run on future versions of the operating system.

### What actually happens

CHKDSK certainly follows the specification and ignores the `AUTORUN.INF` entry which the FAT32 driver doesn't understand, but Windows itself doesn't seem to comply with the specification's requirement to *never look at the reserved bits again*: Any kind of access (other than listing the file and its attributes) is denied.

For example, the command

```
DIR /A /Q
```

states that the owner of `AUTORUN.INF` is `...`. Since FAT32 doesn't support file ownership, it should state `\All`.

The reason for this unexpected behavior is that, according to [FAT32 - Wikipedia # Directory entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#Directory_entry), Windows uses the bit `Y` internally to signal a character device name (CON, PRN, AUX, CLOCK$, NUL, LPT1, COM1, etc.), and it shouldn't be present on storage devices.<sup>2</sup>

In a manner of speaking, **USB Vaccine tricks Windows into assuming that `AUTORUN.INF` isn't an actual file, but a device, which it cannot read from or write to.**

### How to delete the file

If you have direct access to the file system, it suffices to set `Y` to `0` (change the byte `42` to `02`) to make the file deletable again. You could also set the first byte of the directory entry to `E5`, directly marking the file as deleted.<sup>3</sup>

Another option would be to use a different driver. Ubuntu 12.04, e.g., can delete the file without problems. Actually, it automatically "fixes" the directory entry when reading it.<sup>4</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> This attribute is used for, e.g., the volume label or the folder **System Volume Information**.

<sup>2</sup>Certainly enough, setting `X` to `1` doesn't seem to have any effect.

<sup>3</sup>I verified this by changing the corresponding bytes of `C:\vaccinated.img` with a hex editor and writing the modified image to the flash drive using the following command:

```
dd if=C:\vaccinated.img of=\\.\Volume{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}
```

<sup>4</sup> While a blatant deviation from the specification, it seems to be thought-out one. Ubuntu leaves the `X` intact if it is set to `1`, since it does no harm. Setting the `Y` bit to `1` could easily be abused by a malicious application, by, e.g., creating an undeletable file that takes up the drive's entire free space.

Answer (score 6):

This is a clever bit of filesystem trickery that exploits a reserved name in the Win32 namespace. [The details of how Panda USB Vaccine does this is outlined here](http://hype-free.blogspot.com/2009/03/how-does-panda-usb-vaccination-work.html).

Essentially the software creates a folder named `autorun.inf` (which prevents a file with the same name being created there), and then in that folder, a file called `LTP1` is created. In DOS, `LPT1` refers to the printer port, and Windows supports this for backwards compatibility. So when you request a file named `LPT1`, Windows tries to open the printer port, and somehow this prevents the folder from being deleted normally.

As for how to remove the folder/file without formatting the drive, [this Microsoft Knowledgebase article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320081) gives some tips:

> ### Cause 5: The file name includes a reserved name in the Win32 name space
>
> If the file name includes a reserved name (for example, "lpt1")
>   in the Win32 name space, you may not be able to delete the file. To
>   resolve this issue, use a non-Win32 program to rename the file. You
>   can use a POSIX tool or any other tool that uses the appropriate
>   internal syntax to use the file.
>
> Additionally, you may be able to use some built-in commands to bypass
>   the typical Win32 reserved name checks if you use a particular syntax
>   to specify the path of the file. For example, if you use the `Del`
>   command in Windows XP, you can delete a file named "lpt1" if you
>   specify the full path of the file by using the following special
>   syntax:
>
> ```
> del \\?\c:\path_to_file\lpt1
> ```
>
> For more information about deleting files with reserved names under
>   Windows NT and Windows 2000, click the following article number to
>   view the article in the Microsoft Knowledge Base:
>
> > [120716](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/120716)  How to remove files with reserved names in Windows
>
> For more information about deleting files with
>   reserved names under Windows XP, click the following article number to
>   view the article in the Microsoft Knowledge Base:
>
> > [315226](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315226)  How to remove files with reserved names in Windows XP
>
> If you open a handle to a file by using the typical Win32 `CreateFile`
>   mechanism, certain file names are reserved for old-style DOS devices.
>   For backward compatibility, these file names are not permitted and
>   they cannot be created by using typical Win32 file calls. However,
>   this issue is not a limitation of NTFS.
>
> You may be able to use a Win32 program to bypass the typical name
>   checks that are performed when a file is created (or deleted) by using
>   the same technique that you use to traverse folders that are deeper
>   than `MAX_PATH`. Additionally, some POSIX tools are not subject to
>   these name checks.

Comment: That is the old way of Panda USB vaccine of protecting the USB drive from malicious autorun.inf.  Try downloading and using the link I provided and you'll see that it doesn't create any folders.  Just a single file called autorun.inf

Comment: @MegaNairda: Weird... I did install the USB Vaccine, but whenever I try to vaccinate my FAT32 thumbdrive, the program creates an `AUTORUN.INF` (with the same "caacaa..." string mentioned in the article) on the drive and then promptly freezes. I have no problem deleting the autorun file at all...

Comment: Try BitDefender USB Immunizer [link](http://labs.bitdefender.com/projects/usb-immunizer/overview)  Panda USB Vaccine also sometimes freeze on my system when I insert USB drives.

Comment: @MegaNairda: There seemed to be a problem with that thumbdrive. Neither program was able to vaccinate it. However, this coincidence was helpful in it showed that BitDefender's immunizer at least uses a similar technique. The error log showed that it tried to create a series of nested folders/files under `I:\autorun.inf\bdsanitize#\bdsanitize#...` where `#` is "1" or "2". The log file also appended each level's file/dirname with `.dir` or `.file` but that may just be shown for logging/debugging purposes.

Comment: It seems that there is indeed a problem with your USB.  BitDefender's Immunizer do create a folder `autorun.inf` but after that, it would be replaced by a `autorun.inf` **file**.  The difference with the `autorun.inf` Panda USB Vaccine is that the file is empty and doesn't contain the `cacaca` like the one created by Panda.