What does the file Attribute N mean in 7zip?
I'm trying to create a 7z archive, that will be accepted by another program that uses 7z archives to save its files.
The main difference I can see between my archive and one created by the program itself, is that my file has an N Attribute, while the file in the program's archive has no attributes at all:

What does N mean here?

In older versions of Windows, N indicated Not Indexed, but now it means Normal, https://superuser.com/questions/516709/what-is-the-n-folder-attribute-on-windows  . And that evades the answer -- what is Normal, or, for that matter, Abby Normal?
