# File Attributes - AI ...Any clues?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, png

Can anyone point me what does it mean when a `.png` file having 'AI' as `File > Properties > Details > Attributes`.

Does it mean it made with Adobe Illustrator ? Also note that the png is 8bit image.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it's Windows you're using, those are two standard file-system attributes, nothing to do with Adobe.

The `A` stands for *Archive* and the `I` stands for *Indexed*.

> **Archive**: When set, it indicates that the hosting file has changed since the last backup operation. Windows' file system sets this attribute on any file that has changed. Backup software then has the duty of clearing it upon a successful backup.

...

> **Indexed**: When set, Indexing Service or Windows Search do not include the hosting file in their indexing operation.

- Related SU question: [Windows Explorer's file attribute column values](https://superuser.com/questions/44812/windows-explorers-file-attribute-column-values)
- [More info from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_attribute#DOS_and_Windows)

Answer (score 0):

For JPEG there may be [Exif](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format) information embedded in the Image that might give a clue about the software used to create it.
Windows Explorer should be able to read and display these information when you open the properties of the file.