# What do new Windows 8/10 attributes mean: No scrub file (X), Integrity (V), Pinned (P), Unpinned (U)

Tags: windows-10, windows-8, ntfs, file-attributes, attributes

I just opened help for `ATTRIB` command on Windows 10.0.15063, and found out that there are new attributes I didn't know about.

```
>attrib /?
Displays or changes file attributes.

ATTRIB [+R | -R] [+A | -A] [+S | -S] [+H | -H] [+O | -O] [+I | -I] [+P | -P] [+U | -U]
       [drive:][path][filename] [/S [/D]] [/L]

  +   Sets an attribute.
  -   Clears an attribute.
  R   Read-only file attribute.
  A   Archive file attribute.
  S   System file attribute.
  H   Hidden file attribute.
  O   Offline attribute.
  I   Not content indexed file attribute.
  X   No scrub file attribute.
  V   Integrity attribute.
  P   Pinned attribute.
  U   Unpinned attribute.
  [drive:][path][filename]
      Specifies a file or files for attrib to process.
  /S  Processes matching files in the current folder
      and all subfolders.
  /D  Processes folders as well.
  /L  Work on the attributes of the Symbolic Link versus
      the target of the Symbolic Link
```

(specifically, X, V, P, U)

And I can set `+X` via `ATTRIB` command, even though it's not listed as modifiable.

I don't know what they do or used for though. And I didn't manage to google out anything useful except lists not much more useful than the help itself. Even Microsoft' own help does not *help*.[image: I tried googling. Really!]

Comment: I've upvoted all 3 answers to date, since they give useful information, however accepted none as neither correctly explains all attributes I've asked about (DavidPostill's one gives wrong meaning for `P` and misses `U`).

Answer (score 7):

#### There are new attributes I didn't know about.

**`V` Integrity attribute.**

This is related to checking for file corruption:

> Integrity-streams - ReFS uses checksums for metadata and optionally
>   for file data, giving ReFS the ability to reliably detect corruptions.

Source [Resilient File System (ReFS) overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/refs/refs-overview)

> FILE_ATTRIBUTE_INTEGRITY_STREAM
>
> The directory or user data stream is configured with integrity (only
>   supported on ReFS volumes). It is not included in an ordinary
>   directory listing. The integrity setting persists with the file if
>   it's renamed. If a file is copied the destination file will have
>   integrity set if either the source file or destination directory have
>   integrity set.

Source [File Attribute Constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg258117)

---

**`X`   No scrub file attribute.**

This is related to error correction:

> Proactive error correction - In addition to validating data before
>   reads and writes, ReFS introduces a data integrity scanner, known as a
>   scrubber. This scrubber periodically scans the volume, identifying
>   latent corruptions and proactively triggering a repair of corrupt
>   data.

Source [Resilient File System (ReFS) overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/refs/refs-overview)

> FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NO_SCRUB_DATA
>
> The user data stream not to be read by the background data integrity
>   scanner (AKA scrubber). When set on a directory it only provides
>   inheritance. This flag is only supported on Storage Spaces and ReFS
>   volumes. It is not included in an ordinary directory listing.

Source [File Attribute Constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg258117)

---

**`P` Pinned attribute.**

This indicates that the file is a [Sparse File](http://www.ntfs.com/ntfs-sparse.htm):

> A sparse file has an attribute that causes the I/O subsystem to
>   allocate only meaningful (nonzero) data. Nonzero data is allocated on
>   disk, and non-meaningful data (large strings of data composed of
>   zeros) is not. When a sparse file is read, allocated data is returned
>   as it was stored; non-allocated data is returned, by default, as
>   zeros.
>
> NTFS deallocates sparse data streams and only maintains other data as
>   allocated. When a program accesses a sparse file, the file system
>   yields allocated data as actual data and deallocated data as zeros.
>
> NTFS includes full sparse file support for both compressed and
>   uncompressed files. NTFS handles read operations on sparse files by
>   returning allocated data and sparse data. It is possible to read a
>   sparse file as allocated data and a range of data without retrieving
>   the entire data set, although NTFS returns the entire data set by
>   default.
>
> With the sparse file attribute set, the file system can deallocate
>   data from anywhere in the file and, when an application calls, yield
>   the zero data by range instead of storing and returning the actual
>   data. File system application programming interfaces (APIs) allow for
>   the file to be copied or backed as actual bits and sparse stream
>   ranges. The net result is efficient file system storage and access.
>   Next figure shows how data is stored with and without the sparse file
>   attribute set.

Source [NTFS Sparse Files](http://www.ntfs.com/ntfs-sparse.htm)

> FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SPARSE_FILE
>
> A file that is a sparse file.

Source [File Attribute Constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg258117)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [attrib](http://ss64.com/nt/attrib.html) - Display or change file attributes.

Comment: hm how did you link "Pinned" to sparse? Also, how it's possible that "Sparse" attribute can be set or removed via ATTRIB command? And one more: there's «Unpinned» attribute, which is mutually exclusive with "Pinned", but both Pinned and Unpinned can be unset simultaneously (so there is no explanation what is it?).

Comment: @LogicDaemon Because `p` was sparse in previous versions of Windows. There is no indication that the file attributes API has changed for this version of Windows 10.

Comment: @LogicDaemon Note also sparse has disappeared from the list.

Comment: okay, but can you just mark any file sparse? You can mark any file pinned though. No elevation required http://imgur.com/aotouix

Comment: even more: there is "unpinned", which must somehow be linked to "Pinned" , because they are mutually exclusive. But I can't think up what can be mutually exclusive to "sparse" http://imgur.com/NEqVYfV

Comment: one more thing. V and X should only be available on ReFS according to links you provided. I can set X on NTFS though. How can it be? It doesn't do anything, or does it?

Comment: Note that in the latest SDK headers there is `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_PINNED`. This refers to the "Always available on this device" setting for OneDrive files.

Comment: Please note that the +P attribute does not mean "sparse", at least in current Windows 10. It means "pinned", while +U means "unpinned". It is a little confusing for many reasons, but that's the way it is. More info on: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/files-on-demand-windows

Comment: All NTFS file attribute letters are explained here: https://superuser.com/a/982721/415077 Note that some letters are reused, so don't get confused by different uses of the same letter.

Answer (score 6):

There are actually more new attributes found in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.16299.0\um\winnt.h`:

```
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_UNPINNED              = 0x00100000
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_PINNED                = 0x00080000
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_RECALL_ON_DATA_ACCESS = 0x00400000
```

Only the last one is documented at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg258117%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Based on https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/OneDrive-for-Business/Files-on-demand-difference-in-locally-available-and-always/m-p/118203#M2781 my guess is that the "Pinned" flag is used to prevent that the file is purged from local storage when running low on disk space. The "Unpinned" attribute, OTOH, seems to be used to indicate that you want to *force* that the file is not stored locally.

I'm currently investigating how these attributes are used by the new "OneDrive Files On Demand" feature (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Learn-about-OneDrive-Files-On-Demand-0E6860D3-D9F3-4971-B321-7092438FB38E).

See https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/375f3933-fcab-450c-bb9c-da54155549e2/how-do-i-getset-onedrive-files-on-demand-status-from-powershell?forum=ITCG if you want to learn from these investigations.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct to be able to set NO SCRUB(X) with NTFS.
NTFS does check readable and recovers if needed.
Since there is no checksum, NTFS do not check whether the data is correct.
It makes sense only on the redundant Storage Spaces.
This is one of information sources.
[(see slide #30)](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/Australia/2012/WSV316)

P is not sparse attribute.
Because "Get-Item | Format-List Attributes" in Powershell will print "Sparse" when sparse attribute.
But Pinned attribute will be hex value, not meaningful string.
Sorry, I don't know what is pinnd/unpinned.

Comment: Microsoft [says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg258117.aspx) about No scrub (X): «This flag is only supported on Storage Spaces and ReFS volumes». I am not sure what they mean by "supported" or is it related to NTFS. What I doubt though is that there is any background integrity scanning for NTFS, so X won't do anything then (non-background checks, like `chkdsk /r`, will definitely check *No scrub*-marked file anyway)

Comment: [But elsewhere Microsoft says, "NTFS and ReFS support this attribute".](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc232128.aspx#Appendix_A_163) [And this is referred to as FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NO_SCRUB_DATA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc232110.aspx#Appendix_A_Target_163)

Comment: P was Sparse attribute in Windows Explorer. It is the new Pinned attribute that uses the same letter, causing some confusion.