# In Windows, what are the P and U file attributes?

Tags: windows

I downloaded two apps in zip files this morning, and when opening them up in 7-Zip, unusual file attributes appear in the files listed. And when extracted to Windows 10, they appear as P and U, usually together.

Any idea what they stand for? I've never seen them before.

Comment: [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/982721/432690) may advance your research.

Comment: Just for reference, 7-zip will [support these two new attributes](https://sourceforge.net/p/p7zip/bugs/200/) in the new version.