# PS Copy-Item error: Cannot convert value XXX to type "System.IO.FileAttributes" due to enumeration values that are not valid

Tags: powershell

My Copy-Item PowerShell command generates an error that I cannot find any references for.

Using PowerShell 4.x, I am attempting to copy files from the local drive to a remote server (same network/domain). The remote path exists and is empty.

The following `Copy-Item` command from this script generates the following error on (as far as I can tell) every file copied:

```
$SessionTarget = New-PSSession -ComputerName "MYSERVER1"

Copy-Item -Path "C:\Websites\XXX\*" -Destination "C:\Websites\XXX\" -ToSession $SessionTarget -Recurse
```

The error:

```
    Copy-Item : Exception setting "Attributes": "Cannot convert value "1179648" to type "System.IO.FileAttributes" due to enumeration values that are not valid. Specify one of the following enumeration values and try again. The possible enumeration values are "ReadOnly, Hidden, System, Directory, Archive, Device, Normal, Temporary, SparseFile, ReparsePoint, Compressed, Offline, NotContentIndexed, Encrypted, IntegrityStream, NoScrubData"."

At C:\Websites\XXX_Deployment\Deploy.ps1:6 char:1

+ Copy-Item -Path "C:\Websites\XXX\*" -Destination "C:\Websites\XXX ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], SetValueInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionWhenSetting
```

The good news is that the files seem to copy.

Any thoughts on what this error is about?

Thank you!

Comment: looks like one of your files has an illegal attribute. I'd probably try to find out which one with a command like `Get-ChildItem <YOUR_DIR> -Recurse -Force | Select Name, FullName, Attributes` and look for either a point in the list when it crashes, or an attribute that is numeric or otherwise looks corrupted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted my Keith Miller below (thank you!), these values are related to the "new" file attributes.

I located a single file that was getting the error, checked it's current attributes, and found that it had the '(U)' attribute:

'attrib .\MyFile.txt'

(U) 0x100000 Unpinned (OneDrive "online-only files")

I then removed this attribute and was able to use the `Copy-Item` command without error:

attrib .\MyFile.txt -U

This post has a good listing of all the attributes and their bit values:

[Windows Explorer's file attribute column values](https://superuser.com/questions/44812/windows-explorers-file-attribute-column-values)

Answer (score 0):

1179648 = 0x00120000

Those correspond to "newer" attributes:

- `Unpinned = 0x00100000`
- `NoScrubData = 0x00020000`

More info: https://www.google.com/search?q=file+attributes+noscrubdata+unpinned&rlz=1C1JJTC_enUS1014US1014&oq=file+attributes+noscrubdata+unpinned&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i546l3.36771j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: so does that mean that the proposed solution is to upgrade powershell to 5 or 7?

Comment: I don't kknow about 7, but they're not part of the attributes enumeration in 5. I'm pretty sure it's tied to the underlying version of .net, but that's not my area of expertise. Quite likely the servier doesn't recognize those attributes...